# AWS EC2 userdata not copying files from S3 from Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am giving the below command as part of userData while requesting for a spot instance. This command is to copy a file from S3 to the spot instance acquired. I have necessary access to the s3 bucket as well.

```
String startupUserData = "aws s3 cp s3://ugamplatform-spot/python-script/script.py /opt/scripts/";
startupUserData = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(startupUserData.getBytes());

LaunchSpecification launchSpecification = new LaunchSpecification();
    launchSpecification.withKeyName("dev_spot")
    .withImageId("ami-0483f13a861249490")
    .withInstanceType(InstanceType.C4Large)
    .withSubnetId("subnet-3dee5t67")
    .withUserData(startupUserData)
    .withAllSecurityGroups(securityGroups);
requestRequest.setLaunchSpecification(launchSpecification);
RequestSpotInstancesResult requestResult = ec2.requestSpotInstances(requestRequest);
```

I am able to successfully get a spot instance. But the file from S3 is not copied. I don't see any errors in my application logs while requesting an instance

I even tried a simple mkdir command through userData. That dint work as well

Answer (score 2):

You can see the logs of what happened when your userdata ran through the console output using the AWS CLI:

`aws ec2 get-console-output --instance-id i-yourinstanceid`

You can get the instance id using:

`aws ec2 describe-instance-status`

Answer (score 0):

you need to mention region as well ...command for downloading from s3 bucket to any EC2 instance is from us east region is

**aws s3 cp  s3://distribution-bucket/  /path/to/copyOrDownload --region us-east-2**

Comment: It dint work with the region as well. If i login to the acquired spot instance and run this in curl "http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data" , i am able to get the userdata i had passed through Java API. But  it is not working.

Comment: I tried normal mkdir. That doesn't work as well. Could there be any permission issues? Also, if i have to see the logs of what happened while executing userData, where should I check?